# Starting Mongod from within a Shell

Tags: bash, mongodb, shell, gruntjs

I'm attempting to use grunt-shell to run mongod. I've configured mongod and mongo to run correctly from the terminal, but the $PATH for the shell is different. I'm having trouble identifying how I can get this to work. The error is below:

```
Running "shell:mongo" (shell) task
/bin/sh: mongod: command not found
```

grunt-shell code below as well:

```
shell: {
  mongo: {
    command: 'mongod'
  }
}
```

Comment: How about giving the absolute path (something like "command: '/home/rps/bin/mongod'")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue arose because of an issue in the mapping of 'mongo' and 'mongod' commands. Because of this issue, these commands were unavailable from within the shell, meaning that the answer in the mentioned thread did not work.

I was able to resolve the issue by setting the command to the absolute path where mongod was located, overcoming the difference in $PATH:

```
shell: {
  mongo: {
    command: '/mongodb/bin/mongod'
  }
```